# How to read the last result of a while loop using php

Tags: php

i need to put the last while loop result into a variable. How can i return only the last one?

```
<?php

$x = 0;
$r = rand(0,5);
$d = 10 + $r;
$h = 143;

$counter = 0;
while ($h >= 0) {
    echo "The number is: $h <br>";
    $h-=$d;
    
    $counter++;
}



?>
```

Comment: Just assign `$h` to `$lastvalue` in the loop. Then when you exit the loop, `$lastvalue` is the last value.

Comment: it's a common problem to manage limits. There's 143 elements, 142 steps. You need to do something twice. Either you do an echo outside of the while meaning there's 2 echo statement or you use a do_while loop, but in that case, if $h == 0 you will have an issue, therefore you need to check your exit condition twice (one in the while, the other in a if, before the do_while)

Comment: Do you want to view last `echo` or `$h` value ?

Comment: ? the echo its actually the $h value